# Get 1st Day of Week (Sunday)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have this formula in my column to calculate the start date of a given week :

```
dateadd(week,[Week]-(1),
 dateadd(day,(-1),
  dateadd(week,
   datediff(week,(0),
    CONVERT([varchar](4),[Year],(0))+'-01-01'),
     (1))))
```

Where `Week` and `Year` are other fields like `38` and `2012`

Problem is, it calculates the start date of week 38/2012 as a monday (17th Sept), I would like it to be a sunday instead (16th Sept) is this possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Why dateadd(day,(-2)  is not good in this case? With this you will get always sunday as the start of the week.

Comment: @AndrásOttó it seemed like the simplest change but week 1/2011 ended up showing as 26/12/2010... instead of 02/01/2011

Comment: Does dropping the SELECT and FROM.. from my answer give you the same calculated field?

Answer (score 1):

This will return you the first day of the week, given a week number and a year, assuming that the first day of the week is a Sunday.
Standard exclusions apply, e.g. don't try year 1499.

```
declare @tbl table ([Week] int, [Year] int)
insert @tbl select 38,2012
  union all select  1,2012
  union all select  0,2012
  union all select  1,2013

select DATEADD(
    Week,
    [Week]-1,
    DATEADD(
        Day,
        (8-@@datefirst)-DATEPART(dw, CAST([Year]*10000+101 AS VARCHAR(8))),
        CAST([Year]*10000+101 AS VARCHAR(8))))
from @TBL
```

Result

```
2012-09-16 00:00:00.000
2012-01-01 00:00:00.000
2011-12-25 00:00:00.000
2012-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

Note that the Week number starts from 1, and if the week doesn't start on a Sunday, then the first day of that week could end up in an earlier year (row #4).  Because the Weeks are relative, you can use Week 0, -1 etc and it will still give you a result (row #3), rightly or wrongly.

You may also notice I used a different method to create a date out of the year, just as an alternative.

---

The `(8-@@datefirst)` portion of the query makes it robust regardless of your `DATEFIRST` setting.

Comment: Why dont you use `(1-@@DATEFIRST)` and remove the `-1` in `[Week]-1`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first day of the week to be Sunday you could change your database to make it so, using the [DATEFIRST setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't have to be brittle. Handling the DATEFIRST setting is pretty trivial.

Comment: DATEFIRST in a calculated field? (Sorry I forgot to mention the above formula is in a calculated field)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getFirstDateOfThisWeek(d)
    {
        var TempDate = new Date(d || new Date());            
        TempDate.setDate(TempDate.getDate() + (@Config.WeekStartOn - 1 - TempDate.getDay() - 7) % 7);            
        return TempDate;
    }

    var StartDate = getFirstDateOfThisWeek(new Date()); //1st date of this week
```